# angular js post request to nodejs json. key undefined express 4

Tags: angularjs, node.js

https://codeforgeek.com/2014/07/angular-post-request-php/

Hi I was following the above link to give post request from angular js to  node js. I received the data posted in below format when i give

```
console.log(req.body);
{ '{"email":"test@test.com","pass":"password"}': '' }
```

and when i try to get the value as below, it says undefined.

```
var email = req.body.email;
 console.log(email);
```

I am unable to get the value of email and pass. Thank you

Comment: That's a string not an object, where is your Angular code? I mean it's an object but it's not what you want

Comment: I think you sent it wrong from browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the client side header code to headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

Comment: Thank you. That seemed to be the problem. I fixed it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Angular code is sending JSON data, but your Express app is parsing it as URL encoded data.

You probably have something like this in your Express app:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
...
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

That last line should be:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//mongoose.connect(database.url);
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/login', require('./routes/login'));

This my current code, in app.Js

Comment: @AddieVanhala in that case, it seems to me that your client side code isn't sending the correct HTTP headers (to indicate that the body data is JSON)

Answer (score 0):

You did not well explain the problem , please next time try to post a bigger part of your code so we could understand what you wanted to do / to say .

To answer your question i will copy/paste a part of my code that enable you to receive a post request from your frontend application(angularJS) to your backend application (NodeJS), and another function that enable you to do the inverse send a post request from nodeJS to another application (that might consume it):

1) receive a request send from angularJS or whatever inside your nodeJS app

```
    //Import the necessary libraries/declare the necessary objects
var express = require("express");
var myParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();
// we will need the following imports for the inverse operation
var https = require('https')
var querystring = require('querystring')

      // we need these variables for the post request:


      var Vorname ;
      var Name ;
      var e_mail ;
      var Strasse ;


  app.use(myParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
  // the post request is send from http://localhost:8080/yourpath
  app.post("/yourpath", function(request, response ) {
      // test the post request
      if (!request.body) return res.sendStatus(400);

      // fill the variables with the user data
       Vorname =request.body.Vorname;
       Name =request.body.Name;
       e_mail =request.body.e_mail;
       Strasse =request.body.Strasse;      
      response.status(200).send(request.body.title);

});
```

2) Do the inverse send a POST request from a nodeJS application to another application

```
    function sendPostRequest()
    {
        // prepare the data that we are going to send to anymotion  
        var jsonData = querystring.stringify({
                "Land": "Land",
                "Vorname": "Vorname",
                "Name": "Name",
                "Strasse": Strasse,
            });
        var post_options = {
            host: 'achref.gassoumi.de',
            port: '443',
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/api/mAPI',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-Length': jsonData.length
            }
        };
        // request object
            var post_req = https.request(post_options, function(res) {
            var result = '';
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                result += chunk;
                console.log(result);
            });
            res.on('end', function () {
            // show the result in the console : the thrown result in response of our post request
            console.log(result);
        });
        res.on('error', function (err) {
            // show possible error while receiving the result of our post request
            console.log(err);
        })
        });
        post_req.on('error', function (err) {
            // show error if the post request is not succeed
            console.log(err);
        });
        // post the data
        post_req.write(jsonData);
        post_req.end(); 
// ps : I used a https post request , you could use http if you want but you have to change the imported library and some stuffs in the code
    }
```

So finally , I hope this answer will helps anyone who is looking on how to get a post request in node JS and how to send a Post request from nodeJS application.

For further details about how to receive a post request please read the npm documentation for body-parser library : [npm official website documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

I hope you enjoyed this and Viel spaß(have fun in german language).